# How to open a second PowerShell console window from start screen?

Tags: windows-8, powershell

I pressed <kbd>Win</kbd> and typed in "PowerShell". However, since there's already a PS console window open, the computer switched the focus to it, instead of, as I intended, open a new one.

How can I open a **new instance** of a PowerShell console window? Preferably from Start menu. For pedagogic reasons, I need it to be big and blue so starting PS from command prompt won't do in this case.   :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can middle click on the already opened **Windows Powershell** on Windows toolbar below *(It will open an new instance of that program)* or you can also type **powershell** in start menu, but instead of hitting enter, you just right click on Windows Powershell and choose **Open in new window**

Comment: IIRC you can also middle-click start screen/menu entries.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on windows 8

Comment: Hitting middle mouse only opens the start screen on my computer. Perhaps a Win8 thingy? The other suggestion worked, though, as described.

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten: probably

Comment: Tried it again—middle-click definitely works. But then again, I have Windows 8.1. If you don’t, upgrade ASAP. On the task bar it works starting from Windows 7, by the way.

Answer (score 7):

Run at powershell:

```
start powershell
```

May use `Start-Process` or `saps` alias.

Comment: What do you mean by "Run at powershell"? Typing it in in an already-open PowerShell window and pressing Enter?

Comment: I think the OP means run that command **IN** PowerShell - that worked for me, running `start powershell` from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

After typing PowerShell into search, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

`Win + R` - keyboard shortcut to open `run`.

Then type `powershell`. Press enter.

Edit: Windows 10

Comment: This doesn't start a new instance if it's already running

Comment: I have 4 powershell windows open after using this method 4 times. Unless each window is a window onto the same instance, I have 4 separate  instances running. `TaskManager` shows 4 separate powershell instances as well.